# Designing a system for handling in-application economy using currency or credits

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently developing an application where I need to implement some sort of way of handling credits which are purchased by users of my application.  These credits will then be used to preform certain tasks inside my application such as purchasing hits in mechanical turk.  The reason I need to do this is because in the case of mechanical turk there is a possibility that our orders won't be filled and instead of just keeping the extra money for hits they didn't get I want to credit them for future purchases.

The important parts I need help fleshing out is how do you accurately manage an ongoing total of credits.  I can't obviously calculate it every time.  Additionally I need to manage the adding and subtracting of the credits.  Also I probably need to track the origin of these credits, ie money or free because it is possible we might give out free credits as a reward but we need to be careful how to handle turning free credits into cash because it opens an incentive for scammers to use the credits to purchase turk hits then do the turk hit themselves and keep the money.

Comment: Accept more responses to encourage people to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I currently work on a system with something very similar.

Users have an Account which tracks all transactions - origin, type and amount. We have a finite number of transactions types (including obvious the ones like credit/debit). The Account table is therefore actually an archive of all of the transactions for a particular user account, rather than being a simple running total.

Account totals are therefore calculated every time we need them, although it would be pretty simple to add some aggregates to the database that increment/decrement a total value as transactions are processed. As with all performance-related issues - don't do it until you need to, summing values across some smartly indexed columns is fine for our current system.